# Importing Excel data into C# without first row becoming column names?

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, ole

I am trying to import data from excel into a datatable using c#. Here is the code I use to do so...

```
string ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                    "Data Source=" + fileName + "; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;" +
                    "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HRD=No;IMEX=1;\"";
OleDbDataAdapter SheetAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from ["Sheet1"]", conn);
System.Data.DataTable excelData = new System.Data.DataTable();
SheetAdapter.Fill(excelData);
excelData.TableName = "excelData";

foreach (DataRow row in excelData.Rows)
{
   ProcessDataRow(row);
}
```

When I look at the datatable while debugging the first row of data has become the tables column names. I don't understand why this is happening when I put HDR=No into the connection string. Is there a way to force the DataTable to not take the first row as column names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code sample you provided has `HRD=No` instead of `HDR=No`

Comment: Oh my... That was it. I spent waaaay too much time on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used the [NPOI library](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) for just the task you inquired about and more.  The only limitation is that it cannot yet handle the Excel 2007 format, so you are limited to the 97-2003 format.

Comment: I like using my ole data adapter approach. No external assemblies to distribute. Supports all current xls file. and it's not that difficult to use. (Assuming you don't mix up HRD and HDR!)

Comment: @Jordan.  I agree in your situation, it makes sense to just use OleDataAdapter.  However, if/as your application gets more complex and/or your customer wants more features, the route that you have taken will become a dead end.