# How to get data of a column of a sheet by c#

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, oledbdataadapter

I have wrote a winform application that can open and read from a sheet of an excel file.I have used OleDbDataAdapter to read data and then set the data to a datatable. but my problem is that in this datatable the first row of data is used as the name of the columns however i want to use the base names that excel defines for each column (I mean "A B C ... AA AB ..." and so on).

Comment: So you want to be able to grab data by the column ID? Get all data from columb AA?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i want to do. but how???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer [Importing Excel data into C# without first row becoming column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435276/importing-excel-data-into-c-sharp-without-first-row-becoming-column-names)

It seems you need to change the connection string `Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;\"` and make sure `HDR=No` is set.

Comment: I think you did not understand my question. my problem is that when i use the following code to get the data from a sheet it automatically set the first row of the sheet as column name.                                                                  OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet1$]",OleCon);                                                   da.Fill(dt);

Comment: I see what you mean.  Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435276/importing-excel-data-into-c-sharp-without-first-row-becoming-column-names

Comment: Thanks a lot that was worked.but there is another problem yet!! Is there any way to have column names that excel has set for each column (I mean A B C ....) instead of F1 F2 ... when we import the sheet in a datatable????